# ¿Cómo convertir un número con coma como separador de decimales en punto en Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-19c

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos Oracle SQL. En esta tabla hay un campo numérico **NUMBER(9,2)**, con valores que pueden o no tener decimales. **En España, los valores numéricos se muestran con una coma como separador decimal**. Por ejemplo:

- 0,22
- 123
- 15,55

¿Cómo puedo convertir estos números?, en el caso de que sean decimales a:

- 0.22
- 123
- 15.55

He intentado hacerlo con la siguiente instrucción:

```
select TO_CHAR(NOMBRE_CAMPO, 'FM99999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,''')
from tabla;
```

Pero los resultados son los siguientes:

- .22
- 123. 
- 15.55

El único que hace bien es el tercero. En el primer caso, le falta el 0 delante. En el segundo caso, le sobra el punto.

Añado prueba del `replace`, que tampoco funciona. El campo de más a la derecha es el original sin ninguna modificación:
[image: Prueba del replace]

Comment: y no te sirve hacer un replace directmente??? tus numeros vienen con separador de decimal??? o solo la coma???

Comment: @gbianchi, los números se muestran en la tabla con comas. Por ejemplo: 0,22. Si le pongo un replace, en este caso me sale .22. Faltaría el 0 de la derecha.

Comment: @padaleiana. Cuando ves la tabla se muestra directamente 15,55 y cuando ejecuto el select se muestra 15.55

Comment: no. si le pones un replace no puede pasar nunca lo que decis. to_char no es replace.. replace es otra funcion.. vuelvo a preguntar, tus numeros vienen con separadores decimales o solo la coma???

Comment: Entonces, ¿los valores convertidos deberían ser 0.22, 123 y 15.55? Lo pregunto porque, de ser así, hay un error de tipeo en tu pregunta.

Comment: @gbianchi, la columna está definida como NUMBER(12,2) y cuando hago un select normal de esa columna (select columna from tabla) los números decimales se muestran con coma . El replace es lo primero que probé, y no funcionó.

Comment: @gbianchi hice un select replace(campo, ',','.') from tabla

Comment: @padaleiana. Es verdad. Tienes razón. Lo he corregido. Perdón por el error

Comment: Si tu número sobrepasa los 3 dígitos, ¿cuál debería ser la salida? Ej.: `3500`, `2350,35`

Comment: @padaleiana. En el primer caso sería 3500 y en el segundo 2350.35, pero también tengo el problema del 0,22, que lo convierte en .22 y tendría que ser 0.22

Comment: El replace que mostras, deberia mostrar bien los numeros... no deberia mostrar .22 en el caso de 0,22.. asi que, hay otro problema.. o nos estas diciendo mal donde es que ves los numeros, o estas tratando de transformar algo en el lugar equivocado... donde ves mal esos numeros????

Comment: @gbianchi he editado la pregunta y he añadido la imágen con los datos.

Comment: (Si bien _estoy casi segura de que_ la respuesta que dejé responde a la pregunta): ¿Dónde querés visualizar luego los datos (algún reporte, devolverlo en una API, etc.)? ¿O solo estás queriendo ver los registros devueltos en SQL Developer?

Comment: En otra herramienta (como SQL*Plus) ¿hace lo mismo?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la solución.
Es la siguiente:

```
TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TO_CHAR(NOMBRE_CAMPO,'FM99999990D99','NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,'''))
```

Comment: También es válida, y es corta.

Comment: @padaleiana mi conocimiento de Oracle SQL es limitado y no sé exactamente qué hace esa instrucción, pero la he probado y funciona. La he obtenido de Stackoverflow en inglés.

Comment: Para eso esta la documentacion.. que parte no entendes? igual, no me contestaste, porque esto es para solucionar un problema en la ide que estas usando, pero para otras cosas, no sirve para nada, mas que para hacer mas lento el query...

Comment: @padaleiana, mañana podré aceptar la solución. Hoy no me deja

Comment: @gbianchi que yo sepa te he contestado a todo.

Comment: Te preguntamos varias veces, que problema tratas de solucionar con esto.. porque esto solo cambia la representacion visual.. ahora, la queres cambiar para hacer que cosa y en donde??? porque esa representacion tambien depende de la ide que estas usando...

Comment: @gbianchi me lo exigen en el trabajo para crear un fichero de exportación.

Comment: Entonces tu problema no es el query, es como crear ese archivo.. como lo creas???

Answer (score 1):

Hay que tener siempre presente la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-096CA64F-1DA3-4C49-A18B-ECC7518EE56C).

En la consulta proporcionada es necesario un par de ajustes:

1. Caso `.22`: Está devolviendo el número sin el cero frente al separador de decimales porque *ese es el formato que se le proporcionó*. Antes del separador de decimales (`D`), se debe reemplazar el `9` por un `0`: *FM9999999**9**D99* >> *FM9999999**0**D99*
2. Caso `123.`: Está devolviendo el número con el separador de decimales al final porque, si el separador de decimales está presente en la cadena de formato, *no es posible omitirlo aunque el número sea entero*. <sub>(Esto según [esta referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65616105))</sub>. En este caso, lo que se podría hacer es un `CASE` para los formatos: si el valor *truncado* a entero es igual al valor, entonces el formato será de un número entero (sin el `D99` en este caso), sino, se agrega el separador de miles con la cantidad decimales a mostrar:

```sql
CASE
    WHEN TRUNC(nombre_campo) = nombre_campo THEN 'FM99999990' ELSE 'FM99999990D99'
END
```

La consulta (aquí con un CTE llamado *tabla* con datos de ejemplo) quedaría algo así como:

```sql
WITH tabla AS
 (SELECT TO_NUMBER('0,22') nombre_campo
  FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('123') nombre_campo
  FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('15,55') nombre_campo
  FROM   DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_NUMBER('2350,35') nombre_campo
  FROM   DUAL)
SELECT TO_CHAR(nombre_campo, CASE
                    WHEN TRUNC(nombre_campo) = nombre_campo THEN
                     'FM99999990'
                    ELSE
                     'FM99999990D99'
                END, 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,''') resultado
FROM   tabla
```

Con resultado:

| resultado |
| --- |
| 0.22 |
| 123 |
| 15.55 |
| 2350.35 |

Comment: Igual, es un problema de la ide, no de los datos jajajaa... si convierte todo a char, si nada, despues del replace, se acaban los problemas.. su "ide" le esta mostrando esos valores.. tu respuesta es correcta igual...}

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Te referís a cómo OP usa después los datos? Ahí me perdí jaja

Comment: Claro.. op esta haciendo todo este lio, porque el que le hace lio es la IDE en como muestra sus datos... si no, no tendria ningun problema de estos..

Comment: @gbianchi A ver qué responde OP. Personalmente si convierto en un SELECT el formato de los números (punto como separador de decimales) es solo para "no perderme" en la representación al testear ciertas consultas en el IDE (ya que la representación interna en la base de datos a la cual tengo acceso está con coma como separador decimal y punto como separador de miles). (Qué lío repetir palabras, por cierto)